# How to play Python OpenCV 2.4.3 (numpy array) inside a wxPython window

Tags: opencv, numpy, wxpython

I am trying to make my webcam video to be displayed inside a GUI window of the wxPython. So far, all the solutions I found required converting to IPLImage.

I wonder if you guys don´t have any simple code where you get live video with cv2.VideoCapture and display the image from the numpy array inside wxPython window.

Thanks